# Unity - Getting an input action value

Tags: unity-game-engine, input

Unity has a new input system but documentation is shoddy at best, very confusing and not straight forwards at all.

How do I get a simple read out of my input actions value? I have added in the appropriate actions set up as well as code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD6PM.png)

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class S_PlayerInputs : MonoBehaviour
{
public PlayerInput playerInput;
public GameObject ownPlayer;
Rigidbody2D rigiBody;
Vector2 moveDirection = Vector2.zero;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rigiBody = ownPlayer.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    Debug.Log(playerInput.currentActionMap);
    playerInput = GetComponent<PlayerInput>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    Debug.Log(playerInput.Movement.ReadValue<Vector>);
}

void OnJump()
{
    // Jump !!
    rigiBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, 10);
    Debug.Log("Player jumped!");


}

void OnMovement()
{
    //Debug.Log("A or D pressed");
    //moveDirection = playerInput.ReadValue<>;
}
}
```

Doing a simple

```cs
    Debug.Log(playerInput.Movement.ReadValue<Vector>);
```

Doesn't work. The Jump is simple to understand but I need a live readout of the Xaxis value.

Comment: `playerInput.Player.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>()`

Comment: What is .Player. meant to reference? Pasting such a line throws that error. Is this a reference to what?

Answer (score 0):

The following method is the best way to use input action in two modes of reading and determining the method.

```cs
private IA_Main playerInput;
void Start()
{
    playerInput = new IA_Main();
    playerInput.Enable(); // Input Action Initializing..

    playerInput.Character.Jump.performed += OnJump; // Jump initializing..
}
```

Consider a method with `CallbackContext` parameter to jump.

```cs
void OnJump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    // On Jump..
}
```

To read values, it is enough to consider its type as `float`.

```cs
void Update()
{
    var moveAxis = playerInput.Character.Movement.ReadValue<float>();
    Debug.Log(moveAxis);
}
```

### Generate Input Actions C# Code

Click on the file where you specify the keys and be sure to tick Generate C# Class. (InputMaster is the same as IA_Main, which I named in my project.)

---

[image]

Comment: Can't find the namespace of "IA_Main." Something's missing here.

Comment: @Artyu To solve the problem, tick the `Generate C# class` in the keys definition file. I put the guide in the answer update.

Comment: Thank you, but the solution to this was actually just cleaning the code and realising that I had attempted to use 3 different input methods at the same time, old, action maps and hardcoded action maps. OnMovement function was correct, I just needed ```moveDirection = value.Get<float>();``` because the function already knows which keys it needs the value from, rather than declaring all of them again.